# Twilio voice recording is diconnecting the call after 15 seconds

Tags: twilio, record, voice

We are currently testing Twilio Voice API and able to join the call and record but call is disconnecting after 15 seconds. How do we record a call until the caller disconnect the call? Here is the use case:

1. Programmatically dial User A phone number - This is working
2. Record a call  - Currently it is working only 15 seconds and call is automatically disconnecting.

Expecting that Twilio should be able to record the call voice until User A hang the call. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Here is the snippet of code:

```
import com.twilio.Twilio;    
import com.twilio.http.HttpMethod;
import com.twilio.rest.api.v2010.account.Call;
import com.twilio.type.PhoneNumber;
public class MakeCall {
  public static final String ACCOUNT_SID = "xxxxxxx";
  public static final String AUTH_TOKEN = "yyyyyyyy";
  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
      makeCalls("222-333-4444");    
  }    

  private static void makeCalls(String phoneNumber) throws Exception {
      Twilio.init(ACCOUNT_SID, AUTH_TOKEN);
      List<String> callbackEvents = Arrays.asList("initiated", "ringing", "answered", "completed");
      Call call = Call
         .creator(new PhoneNumber(phoneNumber), new PhoneNumber("+12343453456"),
              new URI("http://0ecefc72.ngrok.io/voice.xml"))
              //.setMethod(HttpMethod.GET).setStatusCallback("https://www.myapp.com/events")
              .setRecord(true)
              .create();
              //.setStatusCallbackMethod(HttpMethod.POST).setStatusCallbackEvent(callbackEvents).create();

      System.out.println(call.getSid());

  }
}
```

Best,
Adam

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add your code.

Comment: Twilio developer evangelist here. As Chris has asked, it would be much easier to help you if we could see the code you are testing with. How are you setting up the calls and the recording?

Comment: Added code in the question

Comment: Best course of action would be to get in touch with [support](https://support.twilio.com/hc/en-us/requests/new). They may ask if you want to set up a voice trace on the account to take a deeper look at what's going on with the call. You'll want to send the [`RecordingSid`](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/record#attributes-transcribecallback-parameters) for the 15 seconds that are being recorded and `CallSid` of the parent call of those recordings.